# Can not build V8 for Android on Mac

Tags: javascript, android, v8

I tried following steps to build V8 for Android.

1.Install depot_tools

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
export PATH=`pwd`/depot_tools:"$PATH"
```

2. run “fetch v8” to download the code and all dependencies.
3. cd to v8 and run “make ia32.release” to build.
4. make android_arm.release -j16 android_ndk_root=[full path to ndk]

Step 3 build successfully and got the libraries.
While 4 failed because can't find some standard headers.

```
/Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdio.h:108:15: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include_next <stdio.h>
              ^
In file included from ../src/api.cc:5:
In file included from .././src/api.h:8:
In file included from .././include/v8-testing.h:8:
In file included from ../include/v8.h:20:
/Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdio.h:108:15: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include_next <stdio.h>
              ^
In file included from ../src/asmjs/asm-wasm-builder.cc:5:
In file included from .././src/v8.h:8:
In file included from .././include/v8.h:20:
/Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdio.h:108:15: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include_next <stdio.h>
              ^
In file included from ../src/asmjs/typing-asm.cc:5:
In file included from .././src/asmjs/typing-asm.h:8:
In file included from .././src/allocation.h:8:
In file included from .././src/globals.h:11:
In file included from /Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/ostream:138:
In file included from /Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:90:
/Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:119:15: fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found
#include_next <wchar.h>
              ^
In file included from ../src/accessors.cc:5:
In file included from .././src/accessors.h:8:
In file included from .././include/v8.h:20:
/Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdio.h:108:15: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include_next <stdio.h>In file included from 
../src/assembler.cc:              ^35
:
In file included from .././src/assembler.h:38:
In file included from .././src/allocation.h:8:
In file included from .././src/globals.h:11:
In file included from /Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/ostream:138:
In file included from /Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:90:
/Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:119:15: fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found
#include_next <wchar.h>
              ^In file included from 
../src/arguments.cc:5:
In file included from .././src/arguments.h:8:
In file included from .././src/allocation.h:8:
In file included from .././src/globals.h:11:
In file included from /Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/ostream:138:
In file included from /Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:90:
/Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:119:15: fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found
#include_next <wchar.h>
              ^
In file included from ../src/api-experimental.cc:9:
In file included from .././src/api-experimental.h:8:
In file included from .././src/handles.h:8:
In file included from .././include/v8.h:20:
/Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdio.h:108:15: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include_next <stdio.h>
              ^
In file included from ../src/address-map.cc:5:
In file included from .././src/address-map.h:8:
In file included from .././src/assert-scope.h:9:
In file included from .././src/base/macros.h:8:
In file included from .././src/base/compiler-specific.h:8:
.././include/v8config.h:14:11: fatal error: 'TargetConditionals.h' file not found
# include <TargetConditionals.h>
          ^
In file included from ../src/allocation.cc:5:
In file included from .././src/allocation.h:8:
In file included from .././src/globals.hIn file included from :../src/asmjs/asm-types.cc11::
5In file included from :
/Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/ostreamIn file included from :.././src/v8.h138::
8In file included from :
/Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosIn file included from :.././include/v8.h215::
20In file included from :
/Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:/Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdio.h90::
108:15/Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:: 119:15:fatal error : fatal error'stdio.h':  file 'wchar.h'not  filefound not
 found
#include_next <stdio.h>
              ^
#include_next <wchar.h>
              ^
In file included from ../src/assert-scope.ccIn file included from ../src/ast/ast-expression-rewriter.cc:5:
In file included from .././src/ast/ast.h:8:
In file included from .././src/ast/ast-value-factory.h:31:
In file included from .././src/api.h:8:
In file included from .././include/v8-testing.h:8:
In file included from ../include/v8.h:20:
/Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdio.h:108:15: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include_next <stdio.h>
              ^
:5:
In file included from .././src/assert-scope.h:9:
In file included from .././src/base/macros.h:8:
In file included from .././src/base/compiler-specific.h:8:
.././include/v8config.h:14:11: fatal error: 'TargetConditionals.h' file not foundIn file included from 
../src/api-arguments.cc:5:
In file included from .././src/api-arguments.h:8:
In file included from .././src/api.h:8:
In file included from .././include/v8-testing.h:8:
In file included from ../include/v8.h:20:
/Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdio.h:108:15: fatal error: 'stdio.h' # include <TargetConditionals.h>file
 not           ^found

#include_next <stdio.h>
              ^In file included from 
../src/asmjs/asm-js.cc:5:
In file included from .././src/asmjs/asm-js.h:9:
In file included from .././src/allocation.h:8:
In file included from .././src/globals.h:11:
In file included from /Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/ostream:138:
In file included from /Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:90:
/Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:119:15: fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found
#include_next <wchar.h>
              ^
In file included from ../src/allocation-site-scopes.cc:5:
In file included from .././src/allocation-site-scopes.h:8:
In file included from .././src/ast/ast.h:8:
In file included from .././src/ast/ast-value-factory.h:31:
In file included from .././src/api.h:8:
In file included from .././include/v8-testing.h:8:
In file included from ../include/v8.h:20:
/Users/philip/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdio.h:108:15: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include_next <stdio.h>
              ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [/Users/philip/v8/out/android_arm.release/obj.host/v8_base/src/allocation.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [/Users/philip/v8/out/android_arm.release/obj.host/v8_base/src/asmjs/asm-types.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [/Users/philip/v8/out/android_arm.release/obj.host/v8_base/src/address-map.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [/Users/philip/v8/out/android_arm.release/obj.host/v8_base/src/arguments.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/Users/philip/v8/out/android_arm.release/obj.host/v8_base/src/api-natives.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [/Users/philip/v8/out/android_arm.release/obj.host/v8_base/src/api-arguments.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [/Users/philip/v8/out/android_arm.release/obj.host/v8_base/src/api-experimental.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [/Users/philip/v8/out/android_arm.release/obj.host/v8_base/src/allocation-site-scopes.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [/Users/philip/v8/out/android_arm.release/obj.host/v8_base/src/ast/ast-expression-rewriter.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [/Users/philip/v8/out/android_arm.release/obj.host/v8_base/src/assert-scope.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [/Users/philip/v8/out/android_arm.release/obj.host/v8_base/src/accessors.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [/Users/philip/v8/out/android_arm.release/obj.host/v8_base/src/asmjs/asm-js.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [/Users/philip/v8/out/android_arm.release/obj.host/v8_base/src/asmjs/asm-wasm-builder.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/Users/philip/v8/out/android_arm.release/obj.host/v8_base/src/asmjs/typing-asm.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [/Users/philip/v8/out/android_arm.release/obj.host/v8_base/src/assembler.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [/Users/philip/v8/out/android_arm.release/obj.host/v8_base/src/api.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [android_arm.release] Error 2
make: *** [android_arm.release] Error 2
```

Comment: I also tried to setup the environment with the suggested command:

echo "target_os = ['android']" >> ../.gclient && gclient sync --nohooks         

.While when compile with "sudo make android_arm.release -j16", still get the similar errors.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use the **-j** parameter.

[Source: v8 Wiki](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building%20with%20Gyp)

Optional parameters:

> **-j** specifies the number of parallel build processes. Set it (roughly) to the number of CPU cores your machine has. The GYP/make
>   based V8 build also supports distcc, so you can compile with -j100 or
>   so, provided you have enough machines around.

But now the compiler says, that he can't find TargetConditionals.h

```
.././include/v8config.h:14:11: fatal error: 'TargetConditionals.h' file not found
```

Answer (score 0):

you should install xcode command line tools.

1.install xcode.

2.run command "xcode-select --install" .

3.make android_arm.release -j16 android_ndk_root=[full path to ndk]

Comment: "xcode-select --install" says that xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed,So, I run step 3, throws no archive symbol table (run ranlib) error. My question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366927/v8-build-for-android-on-mac/43368154#43368154