# V8 build for android on mac

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling, v8

I try to build v8 for android on mac. My steps are below  :

1. Install depot_tools
2. fetch v8
3. cd v8
4. git checkout branch-name (last stable version for android)
5. `echo "target_os = ['android']" >> ../.gclient && gclient sync --nohooks`
6. `make android_arm.release android_ndk_root=[full path to ndk]`

It says that

> no archive symbol table (run ranlib)

I search this issue. There is a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5393) for this state. But it is not solved yet.

I try to create d8 and push the android device. How can I do it?

**EDIT**

v8 guide provides [building with GN](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building-with-GN). 
I pass the ndk-root path using `gn gen out.gn/arm.release/ --args='is_debug=false android_ndk_root="/path/android-ndk" target_os="android" arm_arch="armv7-a" android_sdk_root="/path/android-sdk-r25" v8_static_library=true android_ndk_version="r11b"'`

Then I run `ninja -C out.gn/arm.release/`, the error is below :

> ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/libgcc.a', needed by 'obj/libv8_base.a', missing and no known rule to make it

That is right. Because my libgcc under **4.9 folder not 4.9.x**. How can I set libgcc path?

Comment: Have you made any progress since the last time you posted?

Comment: You do not have ndk at under third_party/android_tools/

Answer (score 1):

The up-to-date build instructions are at https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Cross-compiling-for-ARM. Anything that says "make android_arm" is outdated.

However, I don't know if building for Android on Mac is supported. It definitely works on Linux (so you could try in a VM). If something doesn't work, and you want to make it work, we'd happily accept patches; see https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Contributing.

Comment: How can I build v8 with external ndk? Cross complinig guide doesn't say anyting. I run 'export ANDROID_NDK=/path/to/ndk'. Then run 'ninja -C out.gn/arm.release d8'. It says that ligcc does not found. Guide is not enough to build v8.

Comment: By default, the NDK checked out via `gclient` is used, for convenience. The easiest way to use your own is probably to overwrite it, look in `third_party/android_tools/`.

Comment: I delete ndk and move the external ndk under `third_party/android_tools/`. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to set ANDROID_NDK.

step 5:"target_os = ['android']" >> ../.gclient && gclient sync" will download ndk to "third_party/android_tools/ndk"

ndk_version must >= 12.b

Answer (score 0):

We integrated V8 to Skype for Android and open-sourced the docker build script:
https://github.com/Microsoft/v8-docker-buildscript

Feel free to re-use it. It is not completely fair solution, but it is reproducible build on any OS.

V8 team supports Linux build infrastructure also it is well documented.

We succeed building it on Mac but found it too hard to maintain in working condition. At the end we had to patch the Android NDK while chrome build script checkouts working version of NDK and all other required tools.

With docker script any engineer in the team could build the engine from scratch no mater which OS he uses.